# Unexpected value 'Component' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Basically I'm trying to migrate my app to the new angular2 webpack rc5 configuration.

I have this app module generated with the ng cli migration, and I'm trying to put in it a component coming from a library (mine) this is my code, hope you gonna see what I'm missing:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { LandingComponent } from 'mylib'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**LandingComponent**

```
@Component({   
 selector: 'landing',   
 template: `sometemp `,   
 styles: [sometyles],   
 directives : [somedirs] 
})
 export class LandingComponent {   
  @Input() items;   
  @Input() widgets;   
  @Output()
  onMenuToggle = new EventEmitter();   
  toggledMenu: boolean = false;

   constructor() {}

   toggleMenu(){
     this.toggledMenu = !this.toggledMenu;
     this.onMenuToggle.emit({ toggled : this.toggledMenu }) ;   
   }

   onStateChange($event){
    console.log($event);    
    this.toggledMenu = $event.expanded;
   } 
 }
```

**The error is:**
metadata_resolver.js:298
     Uncaught Unexpected value 'LandingComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Try to move all `directives : [somedirs] ` to `declarations of the module. `Component.directives` and `Component.pipes` are deprecated and already removed in RC.6. One component can only be in `directives` of a single `@NgModule`.

Comment: Can you post your project folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete "LandingComponent" from "declarations" section and move to "imports" section.

```
import { LandingComponent } from 'mylib'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
    LandingComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```